# Android Get Image From URL stored in JSONObject

Tags: android, json, android-fragments, imageview

I want to get two images from a url which is in a json array i use JSONParser in async task to get JSON data(url strings) How to load images now and where to do it, I want to show the images in another fragment. I declare 2 Drawables Globallly to Access From another Fragment Activity.

**MainActivity.java**

```
@Override
protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... args) {
    JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

    // Getting JSON from URL
    JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);
    return json;
}
 @Override
 protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject json) {
    try {                
            String Student1Image = json.getString("url1");
            String Student2Image = json.getString("url1");

            } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
 }
```

Now Where and how to load images to be shown in another fragment

**MainScreen.java (Another Fragment)**

```
public class MainScreen extends Fragment {

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.main, container, false);
    new MainActivity();

    ImageView Image = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.imgMainWeather);               
    Image.setImageDrawable(**What to Give Here**);

    return rootView;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do this, pass the ImageView as a parameter to your async task and update it in onPostExecute.

```
public class CustomAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    private ImageView image;

    private ProgressAsyncTask(ImageView image) {
        this.image = image;
    }

    // ... other things here

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject json) {
        try {                
            String Student1Image = json.getString("url1");
            String Student2Image = json.getString("url1");

            // update image view here
        } catch (JSONException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

You can use an image loader library, I recommend Universal Image Loader (https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader)

Comment: I retrived the urls just i want to know how to retrieve image from URL & using what method and where to do it.

Comment: You can use an image loader library, my favorite one is this one: https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
private class DownloadImageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
    ImageView bmImage;

    public DownloadImageTask(ImageView bmImage) {
        this.bmImage = bmImage;
    }

    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {
        String urldisplay = urls[0];
        Bitmap mIcon11 = null;
        try {
            InputStream in = new java.net.URL(urldisplay).openStream();
            mIcon11 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return mIcon11;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
        bmImage.setImageBitmap(result);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
try {
  ImageView i = (ImageView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.image);
  Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream((InputStream)new URL(imageUrl).getContent());
  i.setImageBitmap(bitmap); 
} catch (MalformedURLException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Image Loader classes to load and display images from JSONObject's url in your ImageView.

Have a look at [this sample](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader)

Answer (score 0):

Why using this code, the image from listview refresh continuous?

```
private class DownloadImageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
ImageView bmImage;

public DownloadImageTask(ImageView bmImage) {
    this.bmImage = bmImage;
}

protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {
    String urldisplay = urls[0];
    Bitmap mIcon11 = null;
    try {
        InputStream in = new java.net.URL(urldisplay).openStream();
        mIcon11 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return mIcon11;
}

protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
    bmImage.setImageBitmap(result);
}
```

}

if i use the scroll the first image refresh again and cant stay static